# Problema con ng-captcha Angular 12

Tags: angular, angular12

tengo un problema con ng-captcha en angular 12, no se me renderiza el captcha...
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por favor si alguien podria ayudarme! muchisimas gracias

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: en el console log tienes un error de el api de google, creo que el error puede ser, por que a tu proyecto le asignas desde que dominios pueden acceder a tu api, y solo es cuestión de dar de alta esta.

Comment: Igual saca el error de el api completo para estar seguros de que es.

Comment: al final pude resolver el problema usando 127.0.0.1 en la lista de dominios de google, ya que antes esataba usando localhost y se ve que no me habilitaba el uso, gracias por las respuestas